# How can I fire a jQuery event once getBlocks() actually returns the post's blocks instead of null?

Tags: jquery, block-editor

In the editor, I am trying to loop through all the current post's blocks as soon as everything is loaded and ready for me.

```
wp.data.select("core/block-editor").getBlocks();
```

is able to successfully get all the blocks if I call it manually (via a link/button), but I'd like to have it run automatically.

When that snippet is inside of domReady, a la

```
wp.domReady( function() {...
```

getBlocks always returns null.

I also tried using this Promise

```
wp.domReady( function() {
```

window._wpLoadBlockEditor.then( function() {

```
console.log( "_wpLoadBlockEditor Promise resolved" );

var blocks = wp.data.select("core/block-editor").getBlocks();
console.log( blocks );
```

});

} );

But even it returns null for blocks. It makes me wonder if the Promise is only for the Editor itself being ready; not the actual post content?

If I add a two second delay (via setTimeout), then getBlocks returns all my blocks. Obviously, I don't want to wait an arbitrary amount of time and hope everything is ready.  Is there some way I can ensure my script fires as soon as getBlocks() is ready to actually return the post's blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You need to "subscribe" to changes ([see this issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13555)) with `wp.data.subcribe`.

A more modern version would have you use `useSelect()` to get the blocks. It will automatically update `blocks` if it changes (i.e. it will first return `null`, then an array of blocks once the API request completes).

```js
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

const blocks = useSelect((select) => {
    return select('core/block-editor').getBlocks();
});

if (blocks && blocks.length > 0) {
    blocks.forEach((block) => {
        // Do whatever you want with the block
    });
}
```